# How to find index of a list element

Tags: python

I want to create a program that gives you the position of the string in a list.

```
a = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,"rick",56,"open"]
```

Comment: The position of every string in list or the position of a specific string in a list?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You should read more on operations you can do on Lists here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

In this case, you can use the `index()` function to get the index of a specific item in the list:

```
a=[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,"rick",56,"open"]
print(a.index(7))
print(a.index("rick"))
```

Output:

```
5
9
```

Remember, these indexes are 0-based, so index `5` is actually the 6th element of the list, and index 9 is the 10th element.

Answer (score 0):

If it goes to get all string elements' position:

```
a=[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,"rick",56,"open"]

def find_str(arr):
    res = {}
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            res[value] = index
    return res
```

or just as a shortcut:

```
 def find_str(arr):
    return {value:index for index, value in enumerate(arr) if isinstance(value, str)}
```